# Не работает php-прокси

Tags: php, javascript

Привет. Есть прокси-файл, имитирующий ajax-запрос и передающий его к другому `.php` файлу. Но почему-то файл, в который передаются данные посредством прокси-файла, отдаёт ошибку "undefined index: data". Почему прокси не работает и как это исправить?

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/proxy/proxy.php',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        data:data
    },
    error: function(response) {
        console.error(response);
        throwError('Ошибка сервера', 'На сервере произошла внутренняя ошибка. Сведения об ошибке уже отправлены администратору. Приносим извинения за временные неудобства.');
    }
}).fail(function(response){
    console.log('Error:' + JSON.stringify(response));
}).done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    startSearch(JSON.parse(data.trim()));
});
```

PHP прокси:

```
<?php
require('../../engine/functions.php');
$origin = getDomain($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://search.' . $origin);
if(isset($_POST['data']) && !empty($_POST['data'])) {
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'           => [
                "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest"
            ],
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query(array('data' => $data))
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents('https://' . $origin . '/engine/search.php', false, $context);
    if ($result === false) { 
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
        die();
    }
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    die();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка `"undefined index: data"` говорит о том, что вы пытаетесь обратиться к элементу с несуществующим ключом, вероятно вы где-то забыли `json_decode()`